# Perl using file::slurp read files form a directory return error

Tags: perl

I have been messing with my code for an hour now and still no progress. Please hear me out:
This code worked early today, what it does is open the directory I give to the program, read it, and open each file in the directory and read them individually to perform some actions .

This is the way I do the file opening and reading:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Slurp;

my $dir = shift @ARGV;
opendir(DH, $dir) or die "Directory Open Error!";
my @filelist = grep !/^\.\.?$/, readdir(DH);

my $filename;
foreach $filename(@filelist){
open(FH, $filename) or die "File Open Error!";
my $readFile = read_file($filename);
#more code
}
```

So this works earlier and I have seen the code perform what I want it to do just fine, but when I ran the code on an other directory it returned

> File Open Error! at program.pl line 15

After that I can't make it work anymore, no matter how much I checked I still couldn't figure out what went wrong.

Since the error is on the open() line, I first made sure correct file name was passed down, so I printed the list of file names after the directory was open, everything looks good.

Then I got rid of the open directory part, pass the file name manually:

```
$filename = shift @ARGV;
open(FH, $filename) or die "File Open Error!";
my $readFile = read_file($filename);
```

The program works, file opens just fine. So I got rid of the error message and return to the first code and this is what I saw:

> read_file 'somefile' - sysopen: no such file or directory at
>   program.pl line 17

Line 17 is the line where I used read_file to read the content of a file, this happens after the file is open, I don't understand what's going on now. Again, this code was working earlier just fine and I really didn't change anything except input and now it completely stop working

Comment: You don't need to `open` the file before calling `read_file`. That subroutine handles that for you. Try removing that.

Comment: Sorry I need to read multiple files so I need to close them with FH, but I tried your suggestion, didn't work, same problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to filter-out directories and add $dir to filenames:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Slurp;

my $dir = shift @ARGV;
opendir(DH, $dir) or die "Directory Open Error!";

# here, use grep { !-d "$dir/$_"}
my @filelist = grep {!-d "$dir/$_"} readdir(DH);

my $filename;
foreach $filename(@filelist){
  $filename = "$dir/$filename"; # also add dir
  print $filename, "\n";
  my $readFile = read_file($filename);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an option using [File::Find::Rule](http://search.cpan.org/~rclamp/File-Find-Rule-0.33/lib/File/Find/Rule.pm) to get the file names from a directory.  Omit `->maxdepth(1)` if you want directory recursion.  In this case, `->name(qr/.+\.txt$/i)` filters file names for only text files; omit this option if you don't want the file names filtered.  [squiguy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1114966/squiguy) is correct that `read_file` handles `open`ing files.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Slurp qw/read_file/;
use File::Find::Rule;

my $dir = shift @ARGV or die 'No directory sent.';
-d $dir or die "Directory doesn't exist.";

my @filelist = File::Find::Rule->file()
                            ->maxdepth(1)
                            ->name(qr/.+\.txt$/i)
                            ->in($dir);

for my $fileName (@filelist) {
    my $fileContents = read_file $fileName;

    #more code
}
```

The full file path is provided to `read_file`.

Hope this helps!